Angular/Nx: Using ngPackagrLiteExecutor in custom executor does not derive project dependencies correctly
For a very customzied workflow I need to use the ngPackagrLiteExecutor in a custom executor. However somehow the projectDependencies are not derived correctly and therefore the ngPackagrLiteExecutor fails with the error message that the files of the missing dependant project are not unter the ``.
When I debug nx build styleguide (this is the default generated target by nx), I see that the projectDependencies contain 5 values including @components/components:

When I debug nx build-custom styleguide (this is my custom executor), I see that the project @components/components is missing in projectDependencies.
I believe the error is occouring because of this:

The build-custom target in the styleguide project.json is definded like:
"build-custom": {
      "executor": "@styleguide-repro-nx/my-plugin:echo",
      "options": {
        "ngPackageJson": "libs/styleguide/ng-package.json",
        "tsConfig": "libs/styleguide/tsconfig.lib.prod.json"
      },
      "outputs": ["{workspaceRoot}/dist/{projectRoot}"],
      "dependsOn": ["^build"],
      "inputs": ["production", "^production"]
    },

Initially I missed the dependsOn and inputs and I hoped that this will resolve my issue so that nx can correclty infer the projectDependencies, but it did not help.
My custom executor is looking like this:
export default async function runExecutor(options: EchoExecutorSchema, context: ExecutorContext) {
  const ngPackagr = ngPackagrLiteExecutor({
     project: options.ngPackageJson,
    tsConfig: options.tsConfig,
    watch: false
  }, context)

  await ngPackagr.next();

  return {
    success: true,
  };
}

(Just a very minimal example)
I created a minimal reproduction here:
https://github.com/mikelgo/nx-custom-executor-ng-packagr
You will need to run nx run styleguide:build-custom and than you will see the task failing
It will suceed when running nx run styleguide:build
What am I missing?
